# variable not being assigned correctly, possible scope issue (a function with a switch within each() within getJSON())

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, scope, each

I have a variable that contains an image path. Depending on what integer value I receive for a JSON object, this variable is supposed to get a different path.

However, for some reason within the function below, the path assigned to the variable remains to be the one globally declared, despite the fact that I know for a fact that my JSON object's is returning the right integer for a switch statement. Take a look at the code below:

```
function spawnThumbnails() {
    $.getJSON('scripts/get_thumbs.php', function(data){

        $.each(data, function(thumb, thumbInfo){
            var thumbimage; 
               // If I create local thumbimage var like so, 
               //the image below turns is undefined
               // But if local thumbimage var is not declared,
               // the value defaults to globally declared value of arctic.svg

            var thumbtype = thumbInfo.type;

            alert(thumbtype); // this will alert correct type (an integer)

            switch(thumbtype){
                case 1: thumbimage = 'graphics/thumbs/arctic.svg'; break;
                case 2: thumbimage = 'graphics/thumbs/savan.svg'; break;
                case 3: thumbimage = 'graphics/thumbs/trop.svg'; break;
                case 4: thumbimage = 'graphics/thumbs/tundra.svg'; break;
                case 5: thumbimage = 'graphics/thumbs/ocea.svg'; break;
            }


                $("#thumbtest").append('<img src="' + thumbimage + '">'); 
                // returning as the default image or undefined 

        }); //end each
    }); // end json 
}

var thumbimage = 'graphics/thumbs/artic.svg'; // default image

// I have tried placing the function definition here as well, 
// but there is no difference. Should there be?

spawnThumbnails();
```

I am kind of new to javascript function scopes and such. Am I right in thinking that I should be able to declare the function before the function call and the global variable declaration?

I also find it strange that I do not have to declare a "thumbimage" parameter in the spawnThumbnails function declaration. In fact, if I do declare a parameter, it breaks. But I am guessing this is because it creates a new local variable, am I right?

Thanks for any help! in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Sure that any of the `case`s match...?

Comment: @deceze yep! They weren't matching... nice catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch is doing an identical comparison (`===`). Your variable `thumbtype` is a string, even though it has a numerical value, it's still a string.

The switch is evaluating `'1' === 1` which evaluates to false because of the different types.

Compare it to strings, not integers (notice the quotes)

```
        switch(thumbtype){
            case '1': thumbimage = 'graphics/thumbs/arctic.svg'; break;
            case '2': thumbimage = 'graphics/thumbs/savan.svg'; break;
            case '3': thumbimage = 'graphics/thumbs/trop.svg'; break;
            case '4': thumbimage = 'graphics/thumbs/tundra.svg'; break;
            case '5': thumbimage = 'graphics/thumbs/ocea.svg'; break;
        }
```

Alternatively convert the string to an integer and leave the switch to compare as numbers.

```
thumbtype = parseInt(thumbtype);
```

From ECMA 262 language spec, section 12.11:

> If input is equal to clauseSelector as defined by the === operator, then

Comment: ah, yes! Genius. Of course, like @deceze said, the cases weren't matching. It worked perfectly after this! Thank you. I used the pareseInt method. Now it works the same no matter if I create a local variable of thumbimage or not.

Comment: Glad it's working :) it's an easy mistake to make because the switch in some languages is only an equality comparison instead of identical.